# EBS Service charging even after I delete volume - per IOPS-month provisioned - South America (Sao Paulo)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, billing

I had create a instance in EC2 and I had create a volume in EBS. Just to study AWS environment. But, when I finished I removed all, I had create other things, such as VPC, ig, NAT getaway, subnets and database in RDS, but it was all removed.

Today I received my billing and I was very astonished with value, and I was look and it saw that was charged about this things
$0.091 per IOPS-month provisioned - South America (Sao Paulo)
$0.238 per GB-month of Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1) provisioned storage - South America (Sao Paulo)

But I was look again but I already had removed this it.
I was look in Resource Group - tag service, did it a apply in region South America and North Virginia and not have any active service related about it.

Now, was attributed more one service and the last 1 hour was attributed more $3.
Thank you very much !
[Billing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcRif.png)

[EBS Volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GXeM.png)

[resource group tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzDRl.png)

[resource group tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAfPU.png)

Comment: If this continues, how about using AWS Cost and Usage Report with Resource IDs? The report tells you which resources are charged exactly.

Comment: I went there. It says it's my first time that I visited this service and they're preparing the report and I can come back in 24 hour. Thank you very much !